# Data structures for objects positions, different objects can be indexed by different number of indices

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have structures to describe position for various objects in my project.
Some objects are indexed by two, or three, etc. indices.

In this simple example I show 3 types of position `A`, `B` and `C` and they all
inherit from `Position` which is empty. I inherit from `Position` so that I can
pass these positions in functions that take `Position` argument. The reason why
I don't use a single `Position` structure is that I would have to put all the members
`int a,b,c,d` in it, and for some objects most of the time I will just use `a` and `b`
for example:

```
struct Position {
};

struct A : public Position {
    int a,b,c,d;
};

struct B : public Position {
    int a,b,c;
};

struct C : public Position {
    int a,b;
};
```

The problem is, I have functions like this:

```
City &getCity(const Position &p) {
  const B &pos = (const B &)p;
  return rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c];
}
```

Everything will be OK if I pass position of type `B` to this function, but
what if I pass type `A`? And I need to do that.

Comment: Your code should not work since a, b and c are not a part of the interface for `Position`. I don't understand what you are trying to do here. But you could create a 1-index struct, a 2-index struct that extends the 1-index, a 3-index struct that extends the 2-index struct and so on.

Comment: This code doesn't compile does it?

Comment: Why not have just one position class with linklist/vector of dots???

Comment: Oh sorry missed code, will add it now.

Comment: OK I added the missing code, just for example, and I need to do that also for type A not just B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you actually want a hierarchy of position types, each more specific than the previous, somewhat like this:

```
struct Position1 
{
    int a;
};

struct Position2 : public Position1
{
    int b;
};

struct Position3 : public Position2
{
    int c;
};

struct Position4 : public Position3
{
    int d;
};
```

That way, you can use a `Position4` wherever a `Position1`, `Position2` or `Position3` is needed, and the code will ignore the extra dimensions.

Comment: Actually that is a problem. I don't want to pass extra dimensions when not necessary. This is basically the same as if I would use one Position structure with all members a,b,c,d.

Comment: Well, if you happen to have more dimensions than you need (ie. a `Position4`, when a `Position2` will do), then the code will ignore the extra dimensions.  If you have at your disposal exactly as many dimensions as you need (ie. a `Position2` when that's exactly what you need), then there's no waste.  And if you have insufficient dimensions (ie. a `Position2` when you really needed a `Position4`), the code won't compile because it's a type error.

Comment: But the first is the problem, when you say "the code will ignore the extra dimensions.", so there will be extra dimensions. That is my goal, not to have extra data being passed when it is not needed.